# How to find peace with new boss' "cultural overhaul"

Tags: professionalism, communication, job-change, new-manager

My new boss started barely a month ago, and it was clear the moment they walked in that they had no interest in learning the business.
They immediately jumped to proposing changes and solutions to how our normal processes work.
We are effectively a 2-person office. There is a 3rd, but they are mostly remote.

I was brought into this office ~6 months ago. It was in dire shape and I worked excessively long hours with the prior boss until they were constructively terminated. I created many new systems and resolutions to old problems. I was out for a medical issue for a bit, but I had amazing help from other offices as I recovered and continued to repair the office. I worked very long hours and went above and beyond for clients at every opportunity.

I try to be an amiable person, so I listened and agreed to many of the changes. I was open about where I could improve, things that were still abnormal (from the time before), and excitement to work together.

I also live a very long commute away. I am occasionally late due to this (~5-15mins) but have done my best to improve (getting there earlier) and have always worked well beyond the missed minutes. It has never been an issue... until now.

My new boss lives in town. In the short time they have been here, they have been late a great many times themselves (30+ mins), left early on several occasions, and taken several days off. I have never passed judgment.

They have started criticizing everything I do, finding something to confront about daily.
They are now hellbent on persuing termination for my tardiness. They are using my earliest conversations of confidence as "disciplinary actions".
I have disclosed that I have left earlier and earlier to arrive at the same degree of late.
They insinuate that I am lying.

They lied on the first write-up regarding several dates. (I always write when I am running behind, I have refused to sign at this time).

I get there is no winning in this situation. I'm at fault for my own lateness, but it is blood-boiling to see them be so cavalier about their own.

They are now sneering at systems I have setup for efficiency, and newly insisting upon a heavy-handed division of labor (ie *my tasks/yours* as opposed to dividing tasks for *our* clients).

They have been here barely a month now.

This feels like a constructive termination as I saw my prior boss go through.
I am looking for a new position but need to survive in this one until I can find one.

Is there any way to find peace with this until I find a new position, or is it too far gone?

Comment: are you currently looking for another job just in case?

Comment: @JMERICKS yes, I am actively looking for a new position.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes, I tried discussing these matters with them, but they will press and insist upon their opinion until I say yes/okay/fine. It seems like they have no interest in any degree of compromise (including their disdain for the systems even after I explain the problems they resolve). I am looking, just trying to weather the storm in the interem to be professional with 2 weeks/all that. I really liked working with everyone else at the company.

Comment: Is there a more superior boss to this one, that you could talk to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a mental shift that is needed here. You're basically gone already, as soon as you come to terms with that the frustration will ease and you'll just put in the hours and make nice noises until you can leave.

It's not your business or your responsibility, you're just there for the money.

Answer (score 5):

You have basically answered this question yourself. They are hellbent on firing you. Also note that being late is a perfect excuse for them to fire you so in the mean time I would not be late.

Also immediately start looking for another job this one is unrecoverable. In your next job make sure that the commute is more reasonable and arrive slightly early such that you're not late.

Answer (score -2):

In another thread, the poster had someone complain that he got paid to “learn on the job”. I think we can say clearly that getting paid to learn on the job is ten times better than someone getting paid to jump right in, refusing to learn about anything.

There is not much you can do. That person wants to get rid of you, and has the power to get rid of you, so that’s going to happen. Focus your total efforts on finding a new job. Your work will not be good enough whatever you do, so there’s no reason to put any effort into that. Any review of you, you shouldn’t not just sign, but add a comment about what’s wrong. Might help your successor.

What can we learn from this: You won’t get any “thank you” for hard work you put in in the past.

“Being professional” includes expecting to be treated professionally. If that is not the case, if your company is trying to get rid of you, you owe them *nothing*. Your duty is to take away as much of their money as you can, delivering the least possible results.